# Django 1.9 Create hstore Extension Automatically w/o pre_syncdb

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Now that `pre_syncb` has been removed in Django 1.9, is there a signal that can act the same way as the following code?:

```
@receiver(pre_syncdb, sender=sys.modules[__name__])
def setup_postgres_hstore(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Always create PostgreSQL HSTORE extension if it doesn't already exist
    on the database before syncing the database.
    Requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer.
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore")
```

I know I can run an SQL query easily, but I would like to know any exact alternatives to the code posted above if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [pre_syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-syncdb)

> This signal has been replaced by pre_migrate.

So you can use [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-migrate)

Comment: Awesome! Quick question though as I am not too good with signals - does this mean that all I have to change is the first line to: `@receiver(pre_migrate, sender=sys.modules[__name__])
`?

Comment: @Hybrid  - I haven't really called a signal with a decorator, I'd use `pre_migrate.connect(setup_postgres_hstore, sender=sys.modules[__name__])`